# Put XML string (node value) in server text file and retrieve and echo it again (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

This is my problem. I'm trying to retrieve a value from an XML url (from last.fm api). For example the biography of an artist.

I already know that I can do it simply like this (e.g. for Adele):

```
<?php           
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=adele&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");      
    $info = $xml->artist->bio->summary;
    echo $info;  
?>
```

This returns:

```
Adele Laurie Blue Adkins, (born 5 May 1988), is a Grammy Award-Winning English <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/singer-songwriter" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">singer-songwriter</a> from Enfield, North London. Her debut album, <a title="Adele - 19" href="http://www.last.fm/music/Adele/19" class="bbcode_album">19</a>, was released in January 2008 and entered the UK album chart at #1. The album has since received four-times Platinum certification in the UK and has sold 5,500,000 copies worldwide. The album included the hugely popular song <a title="Adele &ndash; Chasing Pavements" href="http://www.last.fm/music/Adele/_/Chasing+Pavements" class="bbcode_track">Chasing Pavements</a>. 19 earned Adele two Grammy Awards in February 2009 for Best New Artist and Best Female Pop Vocal Performance.
```

I would now like to put that result in a text file and store it on a folder on my website, for example: "http://mysite.com/artistdescriptions/adele.txt".

I've already tried:

```
<?php
    $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/artistdescriptions/adele.txt';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=adele&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");      
    $info = $xml->artist->bio->summary;  
    file_put_contents($file_path, serialize($info));


    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
    if(!empty($file_contents)) {
       $data = unserialize($file_contents);
    echo $data;
    }
?>
```

But this unfortunately didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Have you considered using JSON instead of XML? It works way better with PHP, I think. 2. Can you explain what your program does at this point? Is there a file created and the content isn't what you expect? Is the file not created at all? Is there an error/exception?

Comment: I think that the last.fm api only returns XML about artists, songs, etc... And a file is created indeed. A text file with something like: O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":1:{i:0;s:2:"ARTISTINFO";}

Answer (score 0):

Echo call magic method __toString(), but serialize doesn't, and in SimpleXMLElement isn't serialize allowed, so it throw an Exception. But you can call __toString() magic method by yourself, and this solve you problem.

Replace your line with mine

```
$info = $xml->artist->bio->summary->__toString();
```

Comment: Do I need to do more then just add __toString(); ? Because it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: You have propably turned off reporting error, because when I ran your code, Fatal error was showed (because it can't serialize). Sometimes it wrote, that maximum time to execute script (30s) was exceeded. Loading the XML takes lots of time, they have big delay in their server.
Write to first line `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` and then write, what error it says to you.